# Set several preferred custom voices on MacOS Ventura

Tags: ventura, language, text-to-speech, voice, speech

In Ventura, under System Settings > Accessibility > Vision > Spoken Content > System Voice, I have the option to set a single preferred voice. However, I would like to maintain a preferred voice for language 1 and also a preferred voice for language 2, so that toggling languages lets me easily toggle between my preferred voices. I would like this also for switching between different dialects of the same language, E.g. UK English and US English.

Where are the settings to do this in Ventura?

Comment: Toggling languages where? System Settings ... > Keyboard > Input sources? Language switching within websites?

Comment: Either System Settings,> General > Language & Region > Preferred Languages, or as you said switching within websites.